# Formal logic question - why is this invalid?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I typed this into a logic calculator, and it comes out as invalid:

\begin{align*}
\forall x, & E(x) \implies I(x) \vee A(x) \\
\forall x, & A(x) \implies \neg E(x) \\
\forall x, & E(x) \implies \neg A(x)\\
\exists x, & E(x) \implies I(x)\\
\exists x, & E(x)\\
E(x)⟹I(x)
\end{align*}

Can someone help me explain why it's invalid?

https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((((((%E2%88%80y((Ex%E2%86%92(Ix%E2%88%A8Ax))))%E2%88%A7(%E2%88%80y((Ax%E2%86%92(%C2%ACEx)))))%E2%88%A7(%E2%88%80y((Ex%E2%86%92(%C2%ACAx)))))%E2%88%A7(%C2%AC(%E2%88%80y((%C2%AC(Ex%E2%86%92Ix))))))%E2%88%A7(%C2%AC(%E2%88%80y((%C2%ACEx)))))%E2%88%A7(Ex%E2%86%92Ix))

Comment: I’m a little bit confused about that, can you please give some details?

Comment: @AirMike I used this (http://somerby.net/mack/logic/en/index.html), I used the 'tree proof' generator to figure out why it is invalid, and I also used the 'counterexample' function, but I had trouble reading both. The program uses specific symbols in order to be read properly. You must write it out like this: 

(x,Ex -> Ix | Ax)
(x,Ax -> ~Ex)
(x, Ex -> ~Ax)
(3x, Ex -> Ix)
(3x, Ex)
(Ex -> Ix)

Parenthesis are used for individual premises. I wish I could provide more detail, but as I said, I was confused by the explanation.

Comment: In the second line $Ex$ should be $E(x)$, am I right?

Comment: @saulspatz I didn't use parenthesis at all for the calculator, it all came out as well formed, but invalid. See my above reply for details

Comment: I'm not asking about the calculator, but about what you typed in your question.

Comment: Then yes, it may be right to put E(x)

Comment: Based on your input to the logic calculator, it looks like you are stating $A(x) \implies \neg E(x)$ in the second line, and $A(x) \implies E(x)$ in the question above.

Comment: Yeah I just fixed that

Comment: If you press the link, you'll see, based on a tree proof generator, why it is invalid, they give a counter model, but I'm not sure what it's saying exactly. https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((((((%E2%88%80y((Ex%E2%86%92(Ix%E2%88%A8Ax))))%E2%88%A7(%E2%88%80y((Ax%E2%86%92(%C2%ACEx)))))%E2%88%A7(%E2%88%80y((Ex%E2%86%92(%C2%ACAx)))))%E2%88%A7(%C2%AC(%E2%88%80y((%C2%AC(Ex%E2%86%92Ix))))))%E2%88%A7(%C2%AC(%E2%88%80y((%C2%ACEx)))))%E2%88%A7(Ex%E2%86%92Ix))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment*

As you have written it in the logic calculator, it is a single formula (a conjunction) and not an argument.

Thus, the calculator's answer is correct: the formula is invalid.

As answered by the tool, consider a domain $D = \{ 0 \}$ where we have that $E(0), I(0)$ and $A(0)$ hold. The part $\forall x (Ex \to \lnot Ax)$ is **not** satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The third line is the contrapositive of the second line.  The first and third lines together imply $$\forall x,E(x)\implies (I(x)\lor A(x))\land \lnot A(x)\implies I(x)$$  which is the conclusion.  The fourth and fifth lines are unnecessary, but they don't contradict anything in the first three lines, so the argument seems perfectly valid to me.

I don't know anything about the calculator.

Answer (score 0):

Mauro is right.  If you enter this into the logic calculator at somerby.net/mack/logic

```
x,Ex->Ix|Ax
x,Ax->~Ex
x,Ex->Ix
3x,Ex->Ix
3x,Ex
Ex->Ix
```

it will interpret it as a conjunction of all of the lines, i.e. "Line 1 AND Line 2 AND Line 3 AND ...".  What you need is the "therefore" symbol.  If you enter

```
x,Ex->Ix|Ax
x,Ax->~Ex
x,Ex->Ix
3x,Ex->Ix
3x,Ex
,',
Ex->Ix
```

it will tell you that it is a valid argument, as you expect.  The ",'," means "therefore".  The lines before it are interpreted as the premises of the argument and the line after it are interpreted as the conclusion.